# Custom CSS is not working?

Tags: css, html

I have put the following custom CSS in my WP site's additional CSS setting:-

```
.et_pb_row_2 {
    height:100vh !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
.et_pb_section_2 {
    height:100vh !important;
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

The classes are for a section and row that I created using the Divi theme. You can view this live [here](http://travelcartel.com/).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no et_pb_row_2 classes being used on that page only et_pb_row_1.  Same thing applies to the class et_pb_section_2.